# calling helper intents and calling intent inside another intent

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google

How to call helper intent inside js files. I can see only definition of the intents in online, i am unable to find the calling of the helper intent and How to call intents inside another intent.

```
app.intent('ask_for_place', (conv) => {

     conv.ask(new Place(options));
});
```

Comment: You could create a function that will do everything one of your intent needs to. Then call this function in another intent ?

Comment: I'm not sure if you have two questions here, or if it is one question that is related. You've also showed how to trigger a helper intent - is this not working as you expect? If it is not, what isn't working?

Comment: i am little bit confused, above code is intent definition right? if i want to reuse this "ask_for_place", how to use it?

Comment: Try to check this post [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30273993/javascript-best-way-to-structure-helpers-functions-in-nodejs ] aabout how you may structure and call helpers functions.